# Limiting value vs equilibrium solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I thought that the limiting value and the equilibrium solution for a differential equation are the same. However, this problem asks for both of them as separate questions, implying they are different somehow.

[image]

The solutions manual gives Q=3 for both questions, but arrives at the answers in two different steps.

[image]

Are they the same and the book is just restating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two notions are related but not the same. For a first order equation, if you have a limiting value then it is an equilibrium solution, but you can also have equilibrium solutions which are not limiting values. For instance $y'=y(1-y)$ has the equilibrium solution $y=0$ which is not a limiting value for any nonzero initial condition. For a second order equation, you can have a limiting value which is not an equilibrium solution, due to decaying oscillation around this limiting value.